# How blockchain.info calculate the value transacted

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info, value, output, input

Having this address: https://blockchain.info/address/19tqZYnP9youKtbene2FZiZtZyJYaLeBDw

The last transaction says that this address received `0.0236 BTC`

But even knowing the value in and the value out I am not able to calculate that value:
https://blockchain.info/tx/831c976cb54f27e5a496db749fc9e865c8e077006225d1dfaf61d998fe5a3186

```
In:
---
15Rhv2dsEjFaHzMhPsjGmFxgqCRhCmggjj (0.04583825 BTC - Output)
13LwYeB93Bmo2aWqGyK1ybtF9JiupPFVey (0.029625 BTC - Output)
1BxdV34eTe1YJBJpScGx6jRRVDQBeRf5qj (0.00696224 BTC - Output)

Out:
----
1BTvKHzbfm3RjPMxDZSsG2YYuaEHgfdJNP - (Spent) 0.00045884 BTC
1NCLWFw6F2nJ2pgBWy96K37rbx7VSLZs66 - (Unspent) 0.00239111 BTC
1D7BNbWBPuL22TW6WuoSq5sRrbPAxeJw8g - (Spent) 0.0156 BTC
19tqZYnP9youKtbene2FZiZtZyJYaLeBDw - (Unspent) 0.0236 BTC
1wLbaePtYhh2t5Cgd5NF59LX6Pooe1yLH - (Spent) 0.00920259 BTC
3HXAkXTYvtLzYuudDfNZBMSoueUtvdwXAz - (Unspent) 0.03036754 BTC
```

What I tried is sum all the In's and then substract the Out that has been spent and the fees.

What I am doing wrong? How I can calculate 0.0236 BTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to calculate the in/out values to see how many bitcoins have been "sent" to an address.

You see, **outputs from a transaction can be "locked" to a specific address**. However, the address page on blockchain.info shows all the *transactions* that have resulted in an output being locked to that address.

In the most recent transaction on that page, you can see that **one of the outputs** has been locked to that specific address:

```
Out:
----
1BTvKHzbfm3RjPMxDZSsG2YYuaEHgfdJNP - (Spent) 0.00045884 BTC
1NCLWFw6F2nJ2pgBWy96K37rbx7VSLZs66 - (Unspent) 0.00239111 BTC
1D7BNbWBPuL22TW6WuoSq5sRrbPAxeJw8g - (Spent) 0.0156 BTC
19tqZYnP9youKtbene2FZiZtZyJYaLeBDw - (Unspent) 0.0236 BTC <- this one
1wLbaePtYhh2t5Cgd5NF59LX6Pooe1yLH - (Spent) 0.00920259 BTC
3HXAkXTYvtLzYuudDfNZBMSoueUtvdwXAz - (Unspent) 0.03036754 BTC
```

So that's where they are showing that `0.0236` has been received by `19tqZYnP9youKtbene2FZiZtZyJYaLeBDw`.

I suppose showing entire transactions on an address page can be a little confusing, when it's only the `outputs` that are locked to an address (not entire transactions).

Here is an alternative way of viewing the balance of an address in a blockchain explorer: http://learnmeabitcoin.com/browser/address/19tqZYnP9youKtbene2FZiZtZyJYaLeBDw